# Mongo mongod init.d script not working on CentOS

Tags: mongodb, init.d

I am trying to figure out why the provided init.d script is not working on CentOS.  I tried starting it manually:

```
/etc/init.d/mongod start
```

But I get the following error:

```
Starting mongod: /usr/bin/dirname: extra operand `2>&1.pid'
Try `/usr/bin/dirname --help' for more information.
```

I looked in the script where it tries to start:

```
  daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

So I looked where mongod var is defined:

```
mongod=${MONGOD-/usr/bin/mongod}
```

Also tried:

```
service mongod start
```

Same error.

Not sure what I have setup wrong, but I have verified that I have the latest script but I cannot get mongod process to start.

Any ideas???

Comment: I am seeing similar behavior on Red Hat Linux & MongoDB 2.6.5 - but MongoDB _does_ start regardless of this error.

Comment: @Tommi: for CentOS7 you might want to have a look at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14679?filter=-2

Comment: @lostintranslation: which version of centos are you using?

Comment: i have this problem too. centos 6.6 and mongodb 2.6.5

Answer (score 1):

The following link appears to address the issue well
https://ma.ttias.be/mongodb-startup-dirname-extra-operand-pid/

In a nutshell, a bad script appears to have been distributed but the output it produces is not harmful, mongod still runs. If you run yum update you'll get a fixed script, but likely mongod will still fail because the script was not making it fail. Check your mongo logs (usually /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log, but can be different if specified in differently in /etc/mongod.conf). The log file should tell you the real reason it's failing.

Comment: my mongod process did not start.  I will upgrade to see If that fixes things

Answer (score 0):

Check the mongo pid file location in the config file /etc/mongod.conf:

```
awk -F'[:=]' -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^[[:blank:]]*pidfilepath[[:blank:]]*[:=][[:blank:]]*/{print $2}' /etc/mongod.conf
```

By default there should be this line in mongod.conf: 'pidfilepath = /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid'. Add it if it doesn't exist.

If you are using the YAML version of /etc/mongod.conf, check out this issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13595. In short, you need to change this line in /etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod:

```
PIDFILE=`awk -F= '/^pidfilepath[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*/{print $2}' "$CONFIGFILE"`
```

to:

```
PIDFILE=`awk -F: '/^[[:blank:]]*pidFilePath[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*/{print $2}' "$CONFIGFILE" | tr -d ' '`
```

Comment: Cool, thanks I will try that.  Quick note I can start mongod manually with my config file as well.  mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf.  Doesn't seem like a conf file issue, more so a init.d script issue.  Also the Starting mongod: /usr/bin/dirname error is troublesome, should be trying to start /usr/bin/mongod, /usr/bin/dirname seems like a script variable is screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was in pidfilepath. Init script can't deal with path in format like this

pidfilepath = /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

PIDFILE variable inside of init script contains '  /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid' and not '/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid'

FIX:
replace PIDFILE line with this and it will work.

PIDFILE=`awk -F= '/^pidfilepath[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*/{gsub(" ", "", $2);print $2}' "$CONFIGFILE"`

Comment: Another solution may be https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/50ca596ace0b1390482408f1b19ffb1f9170cab6

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue.

The fix is to make a small change in the script file(`/etc/init.d/mongod`) as mentioned below:

`line 63` i guess:

```
daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

to

```
daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" --pidfile "$PIDFILE" "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score -1):

It could be a RedHat bug on the initscript package:
[goog.le forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/7FuQD3UmcZU/GW1PlBoewhMJ)
[redhat bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1153677)